# Creating a framework where I need to provide developers with a super entity for their core data entities

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsentitydescription

I am creating a framework the utilized Core Data. I have an Entity that I will need developers to specify as the parent entity of entities they make within their app when they want to utilize the framework. What is the best way to allow developers to specify this parent entity that I can provide with my framework?

Comment: Are you going to distribute .xcdatamodel?

Comment: I am willing to do that if it will make the process easiest for developers.

Comment: Are you providing it or is the developer providing it?  I think all you need to do is document how it's to be correctly utilized.

Comment: The way to do this to meet my needs is to compile an app with that entity inside of it. Once that is done if you examine the package contents of the app you will see .mom files as the compiled files representing your entities. You can provide these to developers to import into their own .xcdatamodel files and use.